# php 5.4 nginx ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, php, nginx

How can I get Nginx to work with php 5.4 on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

So far I installed php 5.4 on the server:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5
```

What is next?

Thanks

Comment: What's next is describing your problem in a way that actually lets us help you.  "It doesn't work" is an ***AWFUL*** problem description. Error messages, information from log files, the expected/actual behavior, etc. all contribute to *good* problem descriptions. Right now all we can tell you is [it's dead, and it was a cat](http://www.bsd-box.net/~mikeg/context/).

Answer (score 1):

Have you read http://tomasz.sterna.tv/2009/04/php-fastcgi-with-nginx-on-ubuntu/ or https://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/php-fastcgi/ubuntu-10.04-lucid, and if: where are problems in your setup?

Comment: We really do prefer that answers have content, not pointers to content. This ensures that the answer will remain available even if the link goes dead. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.